# Information On Solr Core shards

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I am working on Solr and some shards core. I did this because the I had once core and reading and writing had gone very slow. But when I had done shards on the big core the reading time didnt change much I was expecting about 3X increase in speed as I made about 5 cores but didnt work.

So, is Solr multithreaded. I am using Solr 1.4 .

Comment: are the cores on the same machine?

Comment: Yes all the cores are on same machine

Answer (score 1):

the main bottleneck of Solr while searching is the hard drive.

try to put the cores on different physical drives or on different machines.

Comment: So you mean to say if I have data distributed on hardrive then its going to fast ?

Comment: i mean you have to put your indexes on different **physical** hard drives, not only on different letters or mount points. the performance will be better. you could also use some SSDs for even better performance.

Comment: Is there solr doc or have you done some performance tests to conclude this ?